# Как вычислить ширину и высоту текста не отрисовывая его?

Tags: javascript, html5, svg

Создаю `SVG` на лету. Необходимо, чтобы всё отобразилось. Сейчас я просто беру и подставляю подогнаные значения в `viewBox`, так как не могу рассчитать ширину и высоту текста. Знаю, что если его отрисовать, то можно получить высоту и ширину блока через `clientWidth` и `clientHeight`. А как расчитать зная  ширину и высоту текстового блока иначе зная шрифт, его размер и регистр?

Comment: проще всего - отрендерить и взять ширину =), как Вы уже умеете делать, что Вас не устраивает в этом подходе?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Как это скажется на производительности? Ведь рендеринг самая тяжелая операция. И является ли в вашей практикой это нормой? Или это больше костыль?

Comment: ну так вы же и так и так его рендерить будете, я не понимаю что Вас смущает

Comment: @StrangerintheQ рендерить уже готовый

Comment: Я предпочитаю чтобы код был простым, и не страдаю преждевремнными оптимизациями, что касается этого случая - это разовая операция, пусть хоть секунду занимает, какая разница?

Comment: В моей практике - главное решить задачу, а сколько при этом будет потеть железка не очень важно. Это не значит что везде надо ездить не бульдозере но и преждевременные оптимизации - это плохо

Answer (score 1):

Вам и так и так придется его отрисовать, один раз сменить bbox - считайте что еще один кадр анимации нарисовать.

Предлагаю отрендерить и узнать размер, сделать это можно при помощи метода `getBBox`

При этом кода ровно одна 2 строчки, а как посчитать размер другим способом - боюсь предположить сколько это будет кода и насколько точен будет результат.

```js
let b = txt.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [b.x, b.y, b.width, b.height]);
```

```html
<svg id=svg>
  <text id=txt>hello</text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: +1, но не приму, так как хочется без отрисовки)

Comment: Просто в моём случае, с вашим подходом мне придётся парсить атрибут `viewBox`. Это конечно понты, но уже смахивает на форшмачёк)

Comment: @doox911 объясните подробнее, не понимаю в чем проблема